# Chrome Extension: 'undefined' errors are ignored?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, error-handling

i am not sure if this is only within chrome extensions but i had a simple undefined error like

```
userInfo.data = blabla;
```

but it had to be

```
userData.data = blabla;
```

The chrome extension is simply stopping at that line without any error. I know it is because there is no such variable 'userInfo' in the context.

I was expecting the famous "Uncaught ReferenceError: userInfo is not defined" error. But it is not coming up. Why?

I tried putting "use strict"; on top, but that seems to be ignored. What am i missing here?

And yes, i can use try-catch here, but still, why is the basic error handling not working here?